# Hiding the "String" part of the code to avoid getting the code exposed

Tags: c++

I have written a program in C++ code and it works as expected. I have compiled this at OS level (Linux SLES SPS 02) by using the standard gnu compiler.

Now the issue is, if I type something like `strings ---name of the compiled file----`, it will show me all the pieces of the code that are in string format.

Say, for example, if i have written a simple hello world program and compiled the output in `Xyz.out` file.

If I try to execute `strings Xyz.out`, it will show me the string `"Hello World"` from the code that I have written.

Is there a way to prevent this? Is there any way I can encrypt my written code?

Comment: how is it compiled? I guess you let debug informations in your binary, you should remove them and additionally strip your binary

Comment: Obviously, your program code needs to know what `"Hello World"` is in order to print it out. So you can't really remove it from your code, but you can obscure/encrypt it in the code itself so that people looking at the compiled executable can't see it. You would have to explicitly un-obscute/decrypt it at runtime before printing it, though.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter unless you're putting stuff like passwords or encryption keys in your code, which you really shouldn't anyway.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel   - the point is i would want to hide the code for security reasons

Comment: @OznOg- g++ <filname.cpp> this is what I have used while compiling it at linux sles OS. I tried the strip -s option but it just removes the symbols not the string